# Blue/Green "deployment" of elasticsearch data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, deployment, blue-green-deployment

I am planning on extracting (essentially scraping, with permission) some data from a web-page and store that in elasticsearch (*you know, for search*).

While I have permission to scrape the data from the site,

- there is no API or another structured source for this data
- it's manually authored straight into HTML
- there are no unique identifiers that differentiate one entry from another (I will essentially be extracting around 1,000-5,000 entries from the DOM).

When I store this in es, I am planning to put this into one index and into a mapping type, say `thing`.

However, over time, the source (the HTML web page) is likely to change as they add/remove/change content of some of these entries. Since there are no identifiers in the source, I can't easily identify new ones (and even worse, deleted ones or changed ones).

I want to keep my es index up to date and what I am thinking is some sort of a blue-green mechanism:

- I run the extraction process at some schedule (daily/weekly) depending on the velocity of the source changing
- Every time it runs the process produces another index (or could be a new cluster altogether). Say the current index is `index-prod` and the new one built by the process is `index-rc` (release candidate)
- It validates `index-rc` based on some heuristics (a flexible velocity check on the number of entries, sample queries that we know should work etc.)
- And if it's valid, it either:

  - A. slowly flips queries into the new cluster/index
  - or B. flips in one shot to the new cluster/index

I am planning on hosting the elasticsearch cluster using [AWS Elastisearch Service](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/) and could possibly concote something using [Route 53 CNAMEs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html) (and maybe ELB?) but I wanted to know if there is a more implicit support in elasticsearch itself for doing this?

Essentially, I want to swap one index's data for another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to swap the entire data between indexes... if I get it right, you can use [Aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html) to change from the actual to the next index version.

To slowly change the queries endpoint, I also suppose that some Load Balancer, like nginx, is the best solution. There are many [cases](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-load-balance-deployment-models/) about this on the web.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-reindex.html) for this.

Comment: reindex looks useful to copy from one to another. I need to re-seed the index. aliases look like the right solution based on the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I heard back on this from another source outside of Stackoverflow.

- [indice aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/indices-aliases.html) solve this problem.
- This is a common occurrence for time-series data. An example of atomically swapping indexes, marking one as **current** and purging old ones is documented in the [ES time series documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/time-based.html).